# Как использовать sqlcipher с динамически добавляемой базой данных

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite

Как использовать sqlcipher с уже готовой базой данных, добавляемую в приложение, а не созданную в нём?
Суть в том, что нужно зашифровать нижеприведенную базу данных sqlite. Я решил это делать с помощью sqlcipher, но в интернете нет ни одного примера с готовой базой данных. 
Приложение должно при переходе из главной активности в активность с уже на тот момент зашифрованной базой данных спрашивать пароль. 
Код класса базы данных:

```
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH; // полный путь к базе данных
    private static String DB_NAME = "AESDataBase.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA = 1; // версия базы данных
    static final String TABLE = "users"; // название таблицы в бд
    // названия столбцов
    static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";

    private Context myContext;

    DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
        this.myContext=context;
        DB_PATH =context.getFilesDir().getPath() + DB_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,  int newVersion) {
    }

    void create_db(){
        InputStream myInput = null;
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(DB_PATH);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                //получаем локальную бд как поток
                myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
                // Путь к новой бд
                String outFileName = DB_PATH;

                // Открываем пустую бд
                myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

                // побайтово копируем данные
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                myOutput.flush();
                myOutput.close();
                myInput.close();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            Log.d("DatabaseHelper", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public SQLiteDatabase open()throws SQLException {

        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
}
```

Код класса в которой находится база данных:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;


public class ActivityList extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txtListView;
    Button b1;
    Button b2;
    Button b3;
    EditText eT;
    ListView listView;
    DataBaseHelper databaseHelper;
    SimpleCursorAdapter userAdapter;
    Cursor userCursor;
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase db_sort;
    long userId=0;
    String key;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        b1 = findViewById(R.id.b1);
        txtListView = findViewById(R.id.txtListView);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        databaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        listView=findViewById(R.id.List);
        eT=findViewById(R.id.eT);
        key=intent.getStringExtra("name");
        String iv = "1234567890987654";
        KeyManager km = new KeyManager(getApplicationContext());
        km.setIv(iv.getBytes());
        km.setId(key.getBytes());



        //создаём БД
        databaseHelper.create_db();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", id);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });



    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
// открываем подключение
        db_sort=databaseHelper.open();
        //получаем данные из бд в виде курсора
        userCursor =  db_sort.rawQuery("select * from "+ DataBaseHelper.TABLE, null);

        // определяем, какие столбцы из курсора будут выводиться в ListView
        String[] headers = new String[]{DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME};
        // создаем адаптер, передаем в него курсор
        userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                userCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
        listView.setAdapter(userAdapter);



        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put(DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, eT.getText().toString());
                db_sort.update(DataBaseHelper.TABLE, cv, DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + String.valueOf(userId),  null);
                db_sort.insert(DataBaseHelper.TABLE, null, cv);
                userCursor =  db_sort.rawQuery("select * from "+ DataBaseHelper.TABLE, null);
                userAdapter.swapCursor(userCursor);
            }

        });
        b2 = findViewById(R.id.b2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                db_sort.delete(DataBaseHelper.TABLE, "_id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(userId)});
            }
        });
        b3 = findViewById(R.id.b3);
        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    databaseHelper.close();
                    userCursor.close();
                    finish();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });
    }

}
```

А так же код класса, из которого переходим в класс с БД:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Base64;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    Button btn_schifr;
    Button btn;
    static EditText edT;
    TextView textView;
    String encrypt;
    String decrypt;
    String outputString;
    String has;

    HasPassword haspassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        haspassword = new HasPassword();

      /*  try {
            AESCrypt aesCrypt = new AESCrypt(edT.().toString());
            encrypt = aesCrypt.encrypt("chuk");
            decrypt = aesCrypt.decrypt("chuk");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/



        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);


        edT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edT);
        //edT.setOnClickListener(this);




        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        //  dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

        btn_schifr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_shifr);


        btn_schifr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



                try {
                    has=haspassword.hasPassword(edT.getText().toString());
                    outputString=has;
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
textView.setText(has);
            }

        });
        // SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        // ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityList.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", outputString);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        }
}
```